# write JSON data in sql

Tags: javascript, sql, sql-server, json

Being a newbie and working on a web application i am stuck at passing a JSON object in Javascript file to a SQL database. I have no clue on how to proceed further. I have created a SQL table with this addon of mozilla https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/
Any suggestions on how to perform this?

Comment: Is your intention to simply store the JSON _string_ ([there's no such thing as a "JSON object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)) in a single database field, or do you want to extract individual properties for storage in separate DB fields?

Comment: My only intention is to store the JSON string in SQL table.The value of the JSON Sring changes on a button click by the user in the application. So every new JSON string is to be stored as a new entry value in the SQL table database. These stored values will be queried again at later point of time.

Comment: "will be queried again" - do you mean that the whole string is read from the database and sent to the client (then a string is enough), or that the database should filter on specific values (then you should store it differently)

Comment: "will be queried again" I mean the values stored in daabase will be filtered and displayed on the client , but this is a separate read operation. Now i am mainly looking to pass the JSON string into a database .

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass JSON object to database then you can use "$.ajax".
Sample Code:

```
   $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "mypage.aspx/mystaticmethod",
            data: "{'fistcolumn':'firstvalue','secondcolumn':'secondvalue'}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (result) {

                });
            }
        });
```

At:

```
data: "{'fistcolumn':'firstvalue','secondcolumn':'secondvalue'}",
```

you can directly send your JSON object and at code behind you will get all values.

```
protected static void mystaticmethod(string firstcolumn, string secondcolumn)
```

Comment: Thanks Amar, i believe this is something i am looking at. But at this point of time i am working on static webpages(html and JS, a website)In the example you mentioned as mypage.aspx. How do i resolve this. Point me with any example ot tutorial if possible

Comment: .aspx is nothing but the location where u want to send your data. u can also send ur data to any webservice hosted. At "url" u can write any url where your service is hosted. U can find out more tutorials on internet which will help you how to write $.ajax